# Can't catch the meaning of the sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

It's from stand-up performance of Josh Blue. "I'm guessing to talk with your manager", this sentence has perplexed me. He thinks that he is talking to the manager right now or he thinks to talk to the manager in the nearest future? https://youtu.be/VMchmxnNb9U?t=263

Comment: The YouTube link is dead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Josh Blue is a comedian who has cerebral palsy, which is a neurological disorder affecting muscle development and movement. It is relatively easy to tell that someone has cerebral palsy by looking at them.

[Wikipedia notes:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerebral_palsy)

> Other symptoms include seizures and problems with thinking or reasoning, which each occur in about one-third of people with CP.

So some people may assume that someone with CP has trouble thinking about things, perhaps to the point of being unable to order dinner at a restaurant.

The joke he is telling here is that, when he was at a restaurant, the server "went around the table" and asked what each person would like. Then instead of asking Josh directly, the server asked his buddy, "What will *he* have?" in a derogatory tone of voice. The buddy's response was:

> Um, I'm guessing "*to talk with your manager*!"

This is not proper grammar, but it conveys the meaning: rather than having "a salad" or "a burger," the buddy *guesses* Josh will have "a talk with the server's manager" (to complain about the discrimination, and perhaps get a free dinner as an apology). It is only a guess because of course Josh can make his own decision about what to do; his buddy does not speak for him.

Comment: Wow, so extensive explanation, couldn't ask for more, thank you so much